# meta tag remove css styling in HTA file

Tags: css, vbscript, hta

I have created a HTA application file. It works fine, but I wanted it to look nice, so have been styling with CSS.

The browser was not styling correctly so I search and found that if I add

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9">
```

it styles everything perfectly, but the downfall to this, I can not use my VBScript scripts in it, if fails

> Error: 'test1' is undefined

If I remove the meta tag and reload the HTA the VBScript scripts work fine but then its ugly again...

Can it be tweaked to actually work and look nice?

My PC is running Windows 8.1 and IE11.

Script example is below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Shortcuts</title>

 <style type="text/css">

 html, body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #BBDEFB;
}

ul{
 padding: 2px;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
}

a{
 color: #EDE7F6;
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover{
 padding: 0px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 padding-right: 5px;
 background-color: #64B5F6;
 -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
 -moz-border-radius: 30px;
 border-radius: 30px;

}

a:active{
 background-color: #42A5F5;
}

li{
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style-type: none;
 background-color: #42A5F5;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px grey;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px grey;
 box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px grey;
}

input{
 background-color: #64B5F6;
 border: 0px;
}

input:focus{
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px grey;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px grey;
 box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px grey;
}

 </style>

<hta:application
 id="Shortcuts_REDO"
 icon="icon.ico"
 version="0.0"
 contextmenu="no"
 singleinstance="yes"
 applicationname="Shortcuts_REDO"
 border="thin"
 borderStyle="normal"
 caption="yes"
 maximizeButton="no"
 minimizeButton="yes"
 showInTaskbar="yes"
 windowState="normal"
 innerBorder="yes"
 navigable="no"
 scroll="auto"
 scrollFlat="yes"
 sysMenu="yes"
 selection="no"
>

<script language="VBScript">

Sub Window_onLoad
 window.offscreenBuffering = True
 window.ResizeTo 250, 650
End Sub

Sub test1
 MsgBox "test"
End Sub

</script>

</head>
<body>

 <input type="button" value="test" onClick="test1" style="height: 22px; width: 100px" Title="Prompt">


<div class="main-container">

<ul>
  <li>Call Templates</li>
  <li><a href="#"> New Call </a></li>
  <li><a href="#"> Existing Call </a></li>
  <li><a href="#"> Follow-up Email </a></li>
  <li><a href="#"> Search Tickets logged </a></li>
  <br>
  <li>...</li>
  <br>
  <li>
    Remote PC
    <input type="text" name="RemotePC" value="pc-" maxlength="10">
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"> Command Prompt </a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onClick="test1"> Notepad </a></li>
  <li><a href="#"> Remote Desktop </a></li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>Wiki Search</li>
  <li>Google Search</li>
  <li>Contacts</li>
  <li>Phone book</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>Active Directory Searches</li>
  <li>Export users or groups</li>
  <li>Password Reset</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>Re-create</li>
  <br>
  <br>
  <select size="1" name="DropDown" onChange="RunLinkSelection" style="width: 100px">
    <option value="1">  ...       </option>
    <option value="2">  Forms     </option>
    <option value="3">  Intranet  </option>

  </select>
  <br>
  <br>
  <li>Settings</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>...</li>

</ul>

</div> <!-- end of main-container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please refer same issue that might be helpful to you :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465094/hta-vbscript-and-css3html5-code-not-running-correctly-when-meta-for-css3-app