# Calling VBScript procedure stops working after adding jQuery to HTA

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vbscript, hta

I'm trying to build an HTA using both VBScript and jQuery.

After completing the main script using VBScript I've come to add the jQuery plugin, however am now experiencing issues running my original VBScript.

I've added

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
```

to the top of my script.

I am only trying to call one sub from the VBS, as per the below button:

```html
<input type=button id=computerstart name=computerstart value='Retrieve Logs'
    width=100px onclick= "vbscript:GetLogs">
```

However, when I click my "Retrieve Logs" button I recieve an error message as below:

> Error : 'GetLogs' is undefined
>   Source: Microsoft JScript runtime error

which looks very much to me like it's ignoring my `vbscript:GetLogs` call?
Looking around I can see different articles stating which language should go first, and whilst I've tried re-positioning the JS above the VBS etc nothing seems to have resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parentheses as follows:

```
<input type=button id=computerstart name=computerstart value='Retrieve Logs'
    width=100px onclick= "vbscript:GetLogs()">
```

**Test `HTA`**:

```
<html> 
  <head> 

    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9" />

    <title>33823891b.hta</title> 
    <HTA:APPLICATION ID = "33823891b" APPLICATIONNAME = "33823891b" >

    <script language="VBScript" type="text/vbscript">
        Sub ExitWindow()
            self.close()
        End Sub

        Sub GetLogs()
          Msgbox document.location & " works"
        End Sub
    </script>
  </head> 

  <body>
    <!-- original does not work with http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9" -->
    <input type=button id=computerstart name=computerstart value='Retrieve Logs'
           width=100px onclick= "vbscript:GetLogs">
    <br><br>
    <!-- adjusted, works with http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9" -->
    <input type=button id=computerstar2 name=computerstar2 value='Retrieve Log2'
           width=100px onclick='vbscript:GetLogs()'>
    <br><br>
    <!-- example, works in both cases -->
    <input id=runbutton type=button value="Exit" onClick="ExitWindow()">
  </body> 
</html>
```

See also [this my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28868070/3439404): `HTA` gives different results with different meta `http-equiv` tags, e.g.

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html">
```

(the latter seems to be the same as if meta `http-equiv` tag is omitted at all). Other [legacy document modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx) not tested.

Comment: Excellent Answer - this has fixed my problem :)
I am forced to use `content="ie=9"` as my script will not begin to execute without it (presumably due to the javascript I'm using.)